# Can you play minecraft on Wii U and Xbox together on mulitplayer?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, minecraft-legacy-console, wii-u

I want to play with my friend but don't know how!

Comment: They are entirely different versions, so you can't.

Answer (score 5):

What you are referring to is called "Cross Platform Multiplayer" Where two or more players on different consoles can play the same game. Currently, Cross platform multiplayer is very rare, and few games have this feature available.

There have been rumors that improved Cross platform multiplayer may be included at a future date on some or all of the minecraft versions, but this is not yet confirmed.(http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/08/05/gamescom-2015-mojang-wants-minecraft-to-work-cross-platform)

Unfortunatly, at the moment, You can only play Minecraft online multiplayer if you, and everyone you are trying to play with are using the same version of minecraft on the same console or platform.

*EDIT
As Pointed out by colorfusion in the comments, Minecraft Pocket Edition is compatible with Minecraft Windows 10 Edition. (Here's an article about it http://www.pcworld.com/article/2982932/software-games/minecraft-pocket-edition-now-lets-windows-10-ios-and-android-gamers-play-together.html)

Comment: "using the same version of minecraft" -  exception for MC:PE and MC:Win10E (they're essentially the same, just available on different platforms).

Comment: Huh, I had no idea. Neat.

Answer (score 1):

No. Your question is slightly vague and could use some editing but I think what you're trying to ask is if you and your friend can play if he has a xbox and you have a wii u. The answer is no. Different systems.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot currently join cross platform with and exeption of Xbox1 and Ps4 but we do know that No hang is working on it so it will come eventually.

*So not you cannot currently play with your Minecraft Buddy on Xbox
*
Thx!

Comment: This answer adds nothing not already covered in far more detail by other answers. Duplicate answers are of no use to anyone and may be deleted.